# HashMap в методы

Tags: java

Нужно вывести все значения HashMap hmap за ключом Group.
Но в метод передается пустой hmap.
Выводит null.
Как передать в метод заполненный HashMap hmap?

```
public class ListGroup {
    static Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> hmap;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ListGroup [hmap=" + hmap + "]";
    }

    public Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> getHmap() {
        return hmap;
    }

    public void setHmap(Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> hmap) {
        this.hmap = hmap;
    }

    public ListGroup(Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> hmap) {
        super();
        this.hmap = hmap;
    }

    public ListGroup() {
        super();
    }

    public static Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> somm() {
        ArrayList<People> people1 = new ArrayList<>();
        people1.add(new People(85, 170, "Gava", "Ivan", true));
        people1.add(new People(120, 180, "Nazumo", "Petro", false));
        people1.add(new People(95, 167, "Dorod", "Marija", true));
        people1.add(new People(69, 170, "Omaee", "Vova", true));

        Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> hmap = new HashMap<>();
        hmap.put(new Group("The Best"), people1);
        return hmap;
    }

    public static void frak(Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> hmap) {
        Set<Entry<Group, ArrayList<People>>> entries = hmap.entrySet();
        for (Iterator<Entry<Group, ArrayList<People>>> iterator = entries.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Entry<Group, ArrayList<People>> entry = iterator.next();
            if (entry.getKey().getName().equals("The Best")) {
                for (Iterator<People> i = entry.getValue().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                    System.out.println(entry);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(hmap);
        frak(hmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: а где у вас должно идти присваивание значения этому самому hmap? как я вижу, с первой же строчки выполняемого кода вы пытаетесь вывести hmap (в котором ещё ничего нет), а затем опять же без всякого присваивания отдаёте его в качестве аргумента =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В потоке выполнения просто нет этапа где заполнялась бы ваша мапа.

Вот вы пишите:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(hmap); 
    frak(hmap); // <--
}
```

Вы вызываете метод `frak`, а в нем только перекидывание ссылок, циклы, и вывод на консоль.

Вероятно заполнение должно произойти в методе `somm`, и что бы было что выводить, вызвать его мне кажется было бы не лишним...

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо. переписала, все работает.

```
public class ListGroup {

    static Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> hmap;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ListGroup [hmap=" + hmap + "]";
    }

    public Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> getHmap() {
        return hmap;
    }

    public void setHmap(Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> hmap) {
        this.hmap = hmap;
    }

    public ListGroup(Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> hmap) {
        super();
        this.hmap = hmap;
    }

    public ListGroup() {
        super();
    }

    public static Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> somm(Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> map) {
        ArrayList<People> people1 = new ArrayList<>();
        people1.add(new People(85, 170, "Gava", "Ivan", true));
        people1.add(new People(120, 180, "Nazumo", "Petro", false));
        people1.add(new People(95, 167, "Dorod", "Marija", true));
        people1.add(new People(69, 170, "Omaee", "Vova", true));

        Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> hmap = new HashMap<>();
        hmap.put(new Group("The Best"), people1);
        return hmap;    
    }

    public static void frak(Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> hmap) {
        Set<Entry<Group, ArrayList<People>>> entries = hmap.entrySet();
        for (Iterator<Entry<Group, ArrayList<People>>> iterator = entries.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Entry<Group, ArrayList<People>> entry = iterator.next();
            if (entry.getKey().getName().equals("The Best")) {
                for (Iterator<People> i = entry.getValue().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                    System.out.println(entry);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Group, ArrayList<People>> map = somm(hmap);
        System.out.println(map);
        frak(map);
    }
}
```